# Show $z^5+3z^2+6z+1$ has exactly one zero on $\partial B_1(0)$ (solution verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want solution verification to show $z^5+3z^2+6z+1$ has exactly one zero on $\partial B_1(0)$. Does the following work?

Define
$$g(z):=z^5+3z^2+1$$
and
$$f(z):=6z$$
Then on the unit circle, we have that
\begin{align}
    \vert g(z) \vert &= \vert z^5+3z^2+1 \vert\\
    &\leq 1+3+1\\
    &=5\\
    &<6\\
    &=\vert 6z \vert \\
    &=\vert f(z) \vert
\end{align}
Where $6z$ has exactly one zero thus $f+g$ has the same number of zeroes by Rouche's Theorem. Or do I need to show more? or? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Except that $1+3+1=4$ isn't quite right. :-)

Comment: And it should be the unit disk $B_1(0)$ and not its boundary $\partial B_1(0)$, right? The function has one zero with $|z|<1$, but none with $|z|=1$.

Comment: @HansLundmark You are right, of course. But $1+3+1=5<6$, so that's not a problem. And, concerning the other comment, I suspect that it was a typo.

Comment: @HansLundmark oops mistake corrected :) thanks super silly mistake

Comment: It zero is $\approx -0.1834$ very far to boundary.